# read the docs does not render API automatically

Tags: read-the-docs

I am really struggling to produce an API automatically on read-the-docs.
Here is the library:
https://github.com/apatlpo/qgsolver

The conda environment is described on the README.md

The doc is found here:
https://readthedocs.org/projects/qgsolver-doc/

Does anybody has ideas about what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, I was ignoring the package from which I was trying to build an API in .gitignore

Because this ignore came late, all but one file in the package were still being pushed to github. This explains why I did not realized the presence of the package in gitignore

Removing the ignore of the package fixed the issue.